# Find the least upper and greatest lower bound of these sets

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me to find (if they exist): the least upper bound, greatest lower bound, the smallest and the largest elements of these sets. $$\left\{ \frac{p-q}{p+q},\space p \text{ and } q\in \mathbb{N},\space p>q\right\}$$ and $$\{x\in \mathbb{Q},\space x^2\leq3 \}$$

Comment: It's considered rude on this site to post in the imperative, rather than asking a question. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: For the first problem, we can find all sorts of sequences going to different things.  For example, take $p=n+1, q=n$.  Then $p+q = 2n+1, p-q =1$.  Then $\frac{p-q}{p+q} = \frac{1}{2n+1}\rightarrow0$.  Similarly, if $p = n+1, q= -n$, we get $p+q = 1, p-q = 2n+1$, so that $\frac{p-q}{p+q} =\frac{2n+1}{1}\rightarrow \infty$.  You can figure out your question from here.

Comment: Do you mean the *least* upper bound and *greatest* lower bound?

Comment: I figure out that $1\geq\frac{p-q}{p+q}>0$, so the problem is how can I be sure that $0$ is the smalest one?

Comment: It *isn't* the smallest one, because it isn't in the set. You *can* show that it's the greatest lower bound, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie how can I show that it's the greatest lower bound?

Comment: Well, consider $p=q+1$, whence $$\frac{p-q}{p+q}=\frac1{2p+1}.$$ This positive number can get as arbitrarily small as we like. What does that let us do?

Comment: @CameronBuie That means $\forall \epsilon>0 \space \exists p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ whit $p>q$ such that $\frac1{2p+1}< \epsilon$ and that's really what we want.

Comment: Bingo. Exactly what we needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to approach the first problem is in two cases, $q=0$ and $q\ne0$.  If $q=0$ then $\frac{p-q}{p+q} = 1$.  If $q\ne0$ then $0 \lt \frac{p-q}{p+q} \lt 1$.

A way to be sure that $\frac{p-q}{p+q} \gt 0$ is to consider when $p$ and $q$ are the closest they can be, $1$ apart. i.e. $p = q +1$.  Then $\frac{p-q}{p+q} = \frac{1}{2q+1} $ and $\lim_{q \to \infty} \frac{1}{2q+1} = 0 $

So an upper bound would be $1$ and a lower bound $0$.  The set contains $1$, $1$ is also the upper bound, so $1$ is the largest element of the set.  The lower bound is $0$, but   $\frac{p-q}{p+q}$ can never be $0$, so the set does not have a smallest element.

note: If you don't take $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ then there is no largest element, because $\frac{p-q}{p+q}\ne 1$.

Comment: I edited that bit for clarity, hope it helps!  But when you say "0 is the smallest one" it's important to realize that it is **not** the smallest element in the set, just a lower bound for the set.

Specifically in your statement with $\alpha$ assume that $p$ and $q$ are such that $\frac{p-q}{p+q} = \alpha$  Now add $1$ to $p$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, let $r = p/q$.
The fraction is, dividing numerator and denominator by $q$ and calling it $f$,
$f = (r-1)/(r+1) = 1 - 2/(r+1)$.

Since $p > q \ge 1$, $r > 1$ and $r$ can be arbitrarily large,
so $f > 0$ (for $r$ close to $1$),
and $f < 1$ (for $r$ large).

There is no largest or smallest element, since the bounds ($0$ and $1$)
are never reached.

For the second, since $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, the upper bound
is not in the set.